# Source of the New and Create Methods in Rails ActiveRecord while using Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, models

I was wondering what the source (i.e., defining class or module) of the New and Create methods is while using associations in Rails.

For example, the Associations section of the Rails guides provides this case:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

And then enters this command in the console:

```
@order = @customer.orders.create(:order_date => Time.now)
```

(Link to Rails Guides section: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

But when I type this:

```
@customer.orders.method(:create)
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `create' for class `Array'
```

Comment: Is there any create method in your Order class ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10430216/1322562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at `collection_proxy.rb` here - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb
Start seeing from **Line 204**, it adequately explains how Rails magically comes out with methods like `build` and `create` in associations.

They are part of `Associations` module and `CollectionProxy` class.

**EDIT:**
Most of these dynamic methods arrive in Rails, thanks to [metaprogramming](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/) abilities in Ruby. `@customer.orders` is also a `Associations`, `CollectionProxy` is a class included in this module and thus supplies these instance methods.

```
@foo = @customer.orders
@foo.included_modules 
#=> List of all `ActiveRecord` and `ActiveModel` modules, it includes.
@foo.include? ActiveRecord::Associations
#=> True
```

Thus, `@foo` gets the honor with methods like `build` and `create` which are present there, unlike, just another `Array` object.

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation as to how the magic happens?  I still need some practice in reading the Rails source code, so that resource isn't as much of a help for me as it might be for others.  I'm still confused as to how I can make a call of new or create on an instance of Array when the Array class doesn't appear to have either one of those methods mixed-in.